# How to change uploader if my Google account was removed by accident?

Tags: dart, gmail, publishing, dart-pub

I have had Gmail account, which I wanted to close and I wanted to make a new one because of the account (and email address) name. I have maintained a project hosted on GitHub and I were publishing to Pub. But after I had removed the old Gmail and had made a new one, I found out that I couldn't publish changes and new versions to my project anymore. I forgot to change uploader to a new one before closing the old Gmail account, which can't be reopenned back.

I can prove, that I am an owner of the GitHub source assigned to the project in Pub, but I can not prove, that I am the holder of the closed Gmail account (unless the account would be restored and I could access it by using my old password).

Could anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the advice from Günter Zöchbauer I wrote the new [issue 23257](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=23257), which solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
pub uploader remove xxx
pub uploader add xxx
```

or for more details

```
pub help uploader
```

Comment: I get a messsage: "You aren't an uploader for package 'package'."

Comment: Your current working directory is in the package you care about?

Comment: If this doesn't work you might create a bug report at http://dartbug.com so it gets fixed manually.

Comment: Yes, it is. But I reinstalled the OS at the same time I closed my old Gmail account.

Comment: You could also just publish it under a new name.

Comment: I know this possibility, but I don't want to change my old name (unless I need to)...